# Is there any way to use a controller with Feeding Frenzy 2 on PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, feeding-frenzy

I was surprised to not see this in the options anywhere.  Is there a way to enable controller use in Feeding Frenzy 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a tool like [Xpadder](http://www.xpadder.com/) to simulate keyboard and mouse input with a Gamepad. There's apparently also a premade profile for Feeding Frenzy 2 for the [Pinnacle Game Profiler](http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/pc-controller-support/alpha-gamepad-joystick/xbox-360-ps3-psx-etc/feeding-frenzy-2), another tool that simulates Gamepad support for games that don't offer it.

Comment: Cool I'll check this out when I get home later.

Comment: By Gamepad does that also include controller support?

Comment: What's the difference between a "gamepad" and a "controller"?